# shorten multiple urls at once using bitly

Tags: ios, url-shortener

How can i shorten multiple urls using bitly at once. I'am using the below API for a single url

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/shorten?access_token=MyAccessToekn&longUrl=http://www.google.com
```

Is there any way to get it for multiple urls. I searched on their API documentation and net could not find any useful info. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Their "[best practices](http://dev.bitly.com/best_practices.html)" give a hint

> Batch Processing: The bitly API does not support shortening more than
>   one long URL with a single API call. However, up to 15 URLs can be
>   handled in one API call using the `/v3/lookup`, `/v3/expand` and
>   `/v3/clicks` endpoints.

Comment: hmm..there is no `v3/shorten` :(